# Can we perform Coded UI Testing on a Remote website provided with just its link?

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

Its just a General question, Can we perform Coded UI Testing using Visual studio 2012 on a Remote website provided with just its link?

I tried adding a website as in existing website in VS2012 but it gives Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 1):

You use a browser on your local computer to visit a website hosted elsewhere. Coded UI works fine driving Internet Explorer.

I suggest you close all browser windows on your computer, run Visual Studio and start recording a Coded UI test. In that test, start Internet Explorer and use it to visit the web site and record all the actions performed on that web site.

Coded UI tests can be recorded with Internet Explorer. There are ways of running the test using some other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I had not tried this before, but it seems you can.  I just wrote one that opened chrome and did a Google search, and another with IE searching Bing and doing some basic navigating.

Instead of trying to import the site, I created a new Coded-UI Test project and recorded some tests there hitting the external sites.